# foreach loop in json encode array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I am sending preformatted HTMl with AJAX JSON,
JSON have below code,

I am trying pull data array from DB and echoing array data,
I am not able to put foreach loop in json_encode, because seems my code is wrong at foreach loop,

How can i achieve that?

```
echo json_encode(array('returnnews' => '<div class="news-item-page">
                                    <h3 class="text-info" style="margin-top:0">'.$latestnews->news_subject.'</h3>
                                    '.$latestnews->news_content.'


                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <ul class="list-inline blog-tags">
                                            <li>
                                                <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>'.
                                                foreach($news_tag_array as $tag){
                                                <a href="javascript:;">
                                                echo $tag </a>
                                               }

                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                               </div>'));
```

Comment: Its really unclear. You need to post your `array` or `json`

Comment: create s string at first, afterwards do the json_encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tags = '';
foreach($news_tag_array as $tag){
   $tags .= '<a href="javascript:;">'.$tag.' </a>';
}
echo json_encode(array('returnnews' =>  '<div class="news-item-page">
                                    <h3 class="text-info" style="margin-top:0">'.$latestnews->news_subject.'</h3>
                                    '.$latestnews->news_content.'
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <ul class="list-inline blog-tags">
                                            <li>
                                                <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>'.$tags.'</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                               </div>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the string first. With all loops which you want.
Then put it into array and send it into `json_encode()`. Get the result.

```
$str = '';
foreach($news_tag_array as $tag){
    $str .= '<a href="javascript:;">';
}
echo json_encode(array(
    'returnnews' => '<div ...'.$latestnews.'</div ... '.$str.' ... ',
));
```